sql отфильтровать дубликаты строк (Значения колонок разные)
Дано выборка:
(с1, с2 - колонки)
c1  c2  
7   181     
181 7       
178 7       
7   178 

Как сделать так чтобы остались только строки
c1  c2  
181 7       
178 7       

Числа и количество приведено просто так.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Mysql Select дубликаты строк + оригиналы

Вот так можно решить данный вопрос:
select least(column1, column2), greatest(column1, column2)
from our_table_example


Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
